# Autofill not working as expected in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel 2003 and I'm trying to autofill a basic formula but it's not working properly for me.

[image]

The formula I'm trying to drag accross takes the value in B2 and adds it to the previous cells value. So the value in F10 is E10+B2 etc. I entered it manually for the first 7 cells and then when I try and drag it accross it starts to reference cells C2, D2, E2 etc. when it should just stay B2.

It does this even though I highlighted a group of previous cells where B2 clearly remains the same.

How to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell Excel to use an absolute cell. When you copy the formula across, the E10 cell changes to F10, G10 etc. Problem is though, the B2 reference changes to C2, D2 etc. To fix, change it to $B$2 - this will prevent horizontal copying from changing the B. It will also prevent vertical copying from changing the 2.

Comment: + 1 yup `$` is the key :)